# how to run both JSP and php on my same machine

Tags: jsp

I am using Xaamp server for php development..Now I have installed Apache and Eclipse to do jsp .Now if I try to execute the jsp page , the Apache server gives error that  several ports 8080,8086etc which are needed is busy even though if I shut down the xaamp server. Is it possible to run both php and jsp page on my same machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[Apache](http://apache.org)" is the name of a big software company which offers many products. I'll assume that you actually mean its product "[Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org)".

Given that you're using XAMPP, you're most likely using Windows. Given that you're a PHP guy using Windows, you've most likely downloaded the Tomcat Windows installer as `.exe` file instead of the Tomcat library as `.zip` file. The Windows installer, which is intented for Windows production environments (and thus not for development environments), will install Tomcat as a Windows service which is automatically started everytime you start Windows (and thus already occupy those ports).

You don't want to use the Tomcat Windows service if you're just developing and want to control Tomcat from inside Eclipse.

Stop the Tomcat service in Windows service manager (*start > run > services.msc*) and/or uninstall Tomcat Windows service. You just need the Tomcat library as `.zip` file. All you need to do was to extract it into the desired location. Once stopped/uninstalled, then you'll be able to start the one in Eclipse without hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure each server to run on a different port. You can configure XAMPP server to run on port 80 say, then Tomcat can run on port 8080. Then it would be no problem to run multiple servers. A quick Google search for "How to change XAMPP port number" will turn up a number of sites that explain this.

Comment: server has also Apache and MySql server inbuilt...and to run jsp we need to start the Apache Tomcat server . Now both runs on different ports. What is the difference between these 2 php-xampp-Apache server and jsp-Tomcat-Apache server ?

Comment: Each server must listen on a different port. So its a matter of listing out all the servers that you have running on your machine: Apache, Tomcat, MySQL etc. Then making sure that each one is listening on a different port. Usually MySQL listens on port 3306 so that may not be a problem. Apache and Tomcat however may both attempt to listen on 8080 so you need to change one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the port that XAMPP uses. To do that:

- Stop the XAMPP server, if it is running already.
- Open the file [XAMPP Installation Folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf.
- Now search for the string Listen 80 (I’m assuming that your XAMPP was using the port 80. Otherwise, just search for the string “Listen”). This is the port number which XAMPP uses. Change this 80 to any other number which you prefer.
- Then search for the string “ServerName” and update the port number there also.
- Now save and re-start XAMPP server and you are done.

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/

Comment: ya,...its works now .One more thing I would like to know --- Xampp server has also Apache and MySql server inbuilt...and to run jsp we need to start the Apache Tomcat server . Now both runs on different ports. What is the difference between these 2 php-xampp-Apache server and jsp-Tomcat-Apache server ?